# Is it possible to clone an NFC/RFID chip that uses IsoDep, NfcA and NdefFormatable

Tags: rfid, nfc

I have an NFC/RFID keychain that looks pretty much like this one:

[image]

When I read it with an Android app called "Nfc Reader", it shows me a specific ID (always the same) and it says that these technologies are used: IsoDep, NfcA, NdefFormatable

Now I'm wondering if it would be possible to clone it, or if these technologies somehow prevent it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do NFC tags prevent copying?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63483/how-do-nfc-tags-prevent-copying)

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63483/how-do-nfc-tags-prevent-copying

Comment: How is my question a duplicate? I'm asking about specific technologies.

Comment: @Overmind I agree it is not a duplicate. This question is about three specific named technologies that the suggested duplicate does not mention, neither in questions nor answers.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned techologies - compare [Android: advanced NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc) - seem completely unrelated to the cloneability issue. NfcA is just ISO 14443, type A commnunication, ISODep is communication protocol and NdefFormatable indicates, that reformatting is supported.

Considering this and the fact that none of these *technologies* addresses some new extended capabilities it still seems a duplicate of the suggested question.